# Not able to write SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a restriction table that stores `coupon_id`, `restriction_value`, and `restriction_type`.

```
coupon_id     restriction_value     restriction_type
-----------------------------------------
1             delhi                 city
2             delhi                 city
1             india                 country
```

I want to return a query which gives me the coupon which is applicable for country India and for city Delhi.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your table DDL, sample data, expected results and what you've tried to date that doesn't work. WIthout this, we cannot really help you.

Comment: Given a coupon write a sql query that give a following result :
"coupon which is applicable for country India and for city delhi"

Comment: the coupon is a separate table?

Answer (score 1):

Query each condition separately, and verify the existence for the same coupon id:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.coupon_id
FROM tableA a
JOIN (SELECT coupon_id FROM tableA WHERE restriction_value = 'delhi' AND restriction_type = 'city') b ON b.coupon_id = a.coupon_id
JOIN (SELECT coupon_id FROM tableA WHERE restriction_value = 'india' AND restriction_type = 'country') c ON c.coupon_id = a.coupon_id
WHERE b.coupon_id = c.coupon_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the coupons for city 'delhi' for which a record with country 'india' exists.
Something like this:

```
SELECT city.*
FROM   my_table city
WHERE  city.restriction_type = 'city'
  AND  city.restriction_value = 'delhi'
  AND  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   my_table country
               WHERE  city.coupon_id = country.coupon_id
                 AND  country.restriction_type = 'country'
                 AND  country.restriction_value = 'india');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write a subquery like below.

```
SELECT
*
FROM coupon_table
where id in (
      select coupon_id 
      from restriction_table
      where (restriction_value = 'Delhi' AND restriction_type = 'city')
            OR (restriction_value = 'India' AND restriction_type = 'country')
);
```

Comment: How to pass where condition in restriction_table .

Comment: I am updating my answer.

Comment: I have added a sample table

Comment: in this coupon id 2 also come...which is not required

Comment: It will come because the 2nd record also has the same data (Delhi city). You can make unique then apply the condition.

Comment: You can put restriction while entering data so there will not be a duplicate (coupons) record for the same city or country.